# How do I set multiple cookies in a single Webrick response?

Tags: ruby, cookies, setcookie, webrick

I use Webrick to test my HTTP client and I need to test how it gets and sets cookies.

Wikipedia [provides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie) an example of such response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: theme=light
Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
...
```

but if I do

```
server.mount_proc ?/ do |req, res|
  res["set-cookie"] = %w{ 1=2 2=3 }
```

the whole array becomes a single cookie: `"[\"1=2\", \"2=3\"]"`

And then in `WEBrick::HTTPResponse` [source code](https://github.com/ruby/webrick/blob/4b5c58a60b399178012c9d5354c3ba2ddec0ee32/lib/webrick/httpresponse.rb#L103) I see again the `@header = Hash.new` that probably means you can't repeat the header key.

Is it impossible?!

**UPD:**

This leaves me no hope:

- https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/52#issuecomment-399629
- https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/c859bbf7b53cb59df1837612a8c330dfb4147392/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb#L98-L100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method should be used instead of `res[...]=`:

```
res.cookies.push WEBrick::Cookie.new("1", "2")
res.cookies.push WEBrick::Cookie.new("3", "4")
res.cookies.push WEBrick::Cookie.new("1", "5")
```